# Sort Structured Numpy Array On Multiple Columns In Different Order

Tags: python, arrays, sorting, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I have a structured numpy array:

```
dtype = [('price', float), ('counter', int)]
values = [(35, 1), (36, 2),
          (36, 3)]
a = np.array(values, dtype=dtype)
```

I want to sort for price and then for counter if price is equal:

```
a_sorted = np.sort(a, order=['price', 'counter'])[::-1]
```

I need the price in a descending order and when prices are equal consider counter in ASCENDING order. In the example above both the price and the counter are in descending order.

What I get is:

```
a_sorted: [(36., 3), (36., 2), (35., 1)]
```

what I need is:

```
 a_sorted: [(36., 2), (36., 3), (35., 1)]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`np.lexsort`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.lexsort.html):

```
a_sorted = a[np.lexsort((a['counter'], -a['price']))]
```

Result:

```
array([(36.0, 2), (36.0, 3), (35.0, 1)], 
      dtype=[('price', '<f8'), ('counter', '<i4')])
```

Just remember the order is reversed, i.e. sorting is performed first by `-a['price']`. Negation takes care of the "descending" aspect.