# How to sort a numpy array by a nested dtype?

Tags: python, numpy, sorting

How do you sort a numpy array by a nested dtype?

I want to sort a numpy array by the first element inside the array

```
import numpy as np
from random import randint

# create dummy data
test = np.array([[[randint(1, 10) for _ in range(3)]] for _ in range(10)])

dtype = [('response', [('x', 'f'),('y', 'f'),('x', 'f')])]

# convert over to dtype
test.astype(dtype)
```

How do I sort on a nested key? as the below doesn't work

```
np.sort(a, order='response.x')
```

What I would like to achieve is to use `np.sort` in the same way I would use `sorted` for a list

```
a_list = [[[randint(1, 10) for _ in range(3)]
sorted(a_list,key=lambda x: (x[0][0]))
```

But I would like to use `np.sort` as this is a sample of a much more complicated problem where I only have access to numpy arrays and would like to work with the numpy methods.

Comment: Look at my answer to https://stackoverflow.com/q/61906820/901925.

Comment: Is the shape of `test` supposed to be `(10, 1, 3)`?

Comment: Yes, it is supposed to be (10,1,3)

Comment: Your example is not reproducible. You probably meant to name the last field `z`.

Answer (score 0):

I understand you have a tensor (three nested arrays), and each array element is a structured data type with nested fields `response.x`, `response.y` and `response.z`.

Since you have a tensor, you can order it in three dimensions (rows, columns and Z-dimension). Default numpy sort behavior is to sort the last dimension, i.e. the innermost array.

To get the sorted indices of the nested data structure, we can use [`numpy.argsort()`](https://numpy.org/doc/1.18/reference/generated/numpy.argsort.html). It gives you the sorted *indices*. For example, the following orders the `response.x`s along the outermost array (i.e. compares rows with each other):

```
order = np.argsort(test['response']['x'], axis=0)
```

You can then use these indices to get the original array ordered. To get the same behavior as `np.sort`, you would use [`numpy.take_along_axis()`](https://numpy.org/devdocs/reference/generated/numpy.take_along_axis.html) with the same `axis` argument:

```
np.take_along_axis(A, order, axis=0)
```

Note that this orders *individual elements* along the rows. This is the same behavior that `np.sort(..., axis=0)` would give you.

However, it seems to me you want to order the entire inner arrays by their first element, i.e. no individual reordering in the inner arrays. To do so, row-by-row, you would do:

```
test[order[:,0,0]]
```

This orders the outermost arrays *as a whole* by the *first* innermost item (0, 0).

The default behavior of `np.sort` would be to order the last dimension, this would be achieved by changing the axis argument in the first example above to `-1` (or removing it completely) in both usages above.